# add item combobox with datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, combobox

I have a method (LoadCustomers()) that returns a dictionary of elements as follows:

```
Dictionary<int, string>()
```

I connected it to the datasource of a combobox like this:

```
             Myclass m = new Myclass();
             combo1.DataSource = new BindingSource(m.LoadCustomers(), null);
             combo1.DisplayMember = "Value";
             combo1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Now I would like to put in front of the list of the combobox an item like:

```
             <select one customer>
```

How to do this in c# on winforms?

Tks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this option to the Dictionary of customers

```
const int EMPTYCUSTOMERKEY = -1;  //be sure Customers will not contain this value
const string EMPTYCUSTOMERVALUE = "<select one customer>";

Myclass m = new Myclass();
Dictionary<int, string> customerSource = m.LoadCustomers();

customerSource.Add(EMPTYCUSTOMERKEY, EMPTYCUSTOMERVALUE);

combo1.DataSource = new BindingSource(customerSource, null);
combo1.DisplayMember = "Value";
combo1.ValueMember = "Key";
```